# Swift - Cut hole in shadow layer

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, calayer, shadow

I want to "cut a hole" in the shadow layer of a UIView an Swift3, iOS

I have a container (UIView), that has 2 children:

- one UIImageView
- one UIView on top of that image ("overlay")

I want to give the overlay a shadow and cut out an inner rect of that shadow, to create a glow-like effect at the edges of the ImageView
It is crucial that the glow is inset, since the image is taking the screen width
My code so far:

```
let glowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight))
glowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: container.bounds, cornerRadius: 4.0).cgPath
glowView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
glowView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
glowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
glowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4

container.addSubview(imageView)
container.addSubview(glowView)
```

The result looks like the following right now:

[image]

Now I would like to cut out the darker inner part, so that just the shadow at the edges remains
Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Add the glow view before the image view. This should work

Comment: sorry, did not mention it, but I can't do this, because the image is taking all the width and the glow needs to be inset

Comment: @skaldesh , if you're still watching, there's a much much easier way to do this!  I put in an answer, cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Fortunately it's now very easy today (2020)

These days it's very easy to do this:

[image]

Here's the whole thing

```
import UIKit
class GlowBox: UIView {
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        backgroundColor = .clear
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        layer.shadowRadius = 3
        
        let p = UIBezierPath(
             roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0),
             cornerRadius: 4)
        let hole = UIBezierPath(
             roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: 2, dy: 2),
             cornerRadius: 3)
             .reversing()
        p.append(hole)
        layer.shadowPath = p.cgPath
    }
}
```

## A really handy tip:

When you add (that is  `.append` ) two bezier paths like that...

The second one has to be either "normal" or "reversed".

Notice the line of code near the end:

```
             .reversing()
```

Like most programmers, **I can NEVER REMEMBER** if it should be "normal" or "reversed" in different cases!!

The simple solution ...

Very simply, try both!

Simply try it with, and without, the `.reversing()`

It will work one way or the other!  :)

## If you want JUST the shadow to be ONLY outside, with the insides exactly cut out:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    // take EXTREME CARE of frame vs. bounds
    // and + vs - throughout this function:

    let _rad: CGRect = 42
    colorAndShadow.frame = bounds
    colorAndShadow.path =
       UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: _rad).cgPath
    
    let enuff: CGFloat = 200
    
    shadowHole.frame = colorAndShadow.frame.insetBy(dx: -enuff, dy: -enuff)
    
    let _sb = shadowHole.bounds
    let p = UIBezierPath(rect: _sb)
    let h = UIBezierPath(
      roundedRect: _sb.insetBy(dx: enuff, dy: enuff),
      cornerRadius: _rad)
    
    p.append(h)
    shadowHole.fillRule = .evenOdd
    shadowHole.path = p.cgPath
    
    layer.mask = shadowHole
}
```

`shadowHole` is a CAShapeLayer that you must set up using a lazy variable in the usual way.

Comment: Cool solution :)

Comment: thanks @skaldesh - you rock.  yes, it's one of those things where it has fortunately become extremely easy these days!  cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try using this as as your shadow path:

```
let shadowWidth = 2.0 // Do this as wide as you want
var outterPath = UIBezierPath()
outterPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: shadowWidth, y: 0))
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: glowView.bounds.size.width, y: 0))
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: glowView.bounds.size.width, y: glowView.bounds.size.height))
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: glowView.bounds.size.height))
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: shadowWidth, y: 0.0))
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: shadowWidth, y: glowView.bounds.size.height - shadowWidth))
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: glowView.bounds.size.width - shadowWidth, y: glowView.bounds.size.height - shadowWidth))
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: glowView.bounds.size.width - shadowWidth, y: shadowWidth))
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: shadowWidth, y: shadowWidth))
outterPath.close()
```

This won't create a rounded rect but with a little bit of changes to the code above you should be able to add those too.

Comment: Thanks, that was a very good foundation for my approach! I will make an answer and reference your answer there!

Comment: anyone googling here, there is a tremendously easier way to do this (also with the correct corners etc.), I typed in an answer

Answer (score -3):

Thanks to [Mihai Fratu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43232699/5341805) I was able to create a UIBezierPath that exactly meets my needs
I post my code here in case somebody has the same problem later

```
let innerRadius: CGFloat = 32.0 * UIScreen.main.scale
let shadowPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.view.bounds, cornerRadius: self.cornerRadius)
//shadowPath.append(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 8, dy: 8), cornerRadius: self.cornerRadius))
let shadowWidth: CGFloat = 8.0 // Do this as wide as you want
var outterPath = UIBezierPath()
// Start at the top left corner with an x offset of the cornerRadius
outterPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.cornerRadius, y: 0))

// Draw a line to the top right corner
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: glowView.bounds.size.width - self.cornerRadius, y: 0))
//Draw the round top right corner
outterPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: glowView.bounds.size.width - self.cornerRadius, y: self.cornerRadius), radius: self.cornerRadius, startAngle: (3 * CGFloat.pi) / 2, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)

// Draw a line to the bottom right corner
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: glowView.bounds.size.width, y: glowView.bounds.size.height - self.cornerRadius))
// Draw the round bottom right corner
outterPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: glowView.bounds.size.width - self.cornerRadius, y: glowView.bounds.size.height -  self.cornerRadius), radius: self.cornerRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, clockwise: true)

// Draw a line to the bottom left corner
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.cornerRadius, y: glowView.bounds.size.height))
// Draw the round bottom left corner
outterPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: self.cornerRadius, y: glowView.bounds.size.height -  self.cornerRadius), radius: self.cornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

// Draw a line to the top left corner
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: self.cornerRadius))
// Draw the round top left corner
outterPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: self.cornerRadius, y: self.cornerRadius), radius: self.cornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: (3 * CGFloat.pi) / 2, clockwise: true)

// Move to the inner start point and add the paths counterclockwise to prevent the filling of the inner area
outterPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: shadowWidth + innerRadius, y: shadowWidth))
// Draw the inner top left corner
outterPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: shadowWidth + innerRadius, y: shadowWidth + innerRadius), radius: innerRadius, startAngle: (3 * CGFloat.pi) / 2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi, clockwise: false)

// Draw a line to the inner bottom left corner
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: shadowWidth, y: glowView.bounds.size.height - innerRadius - shadowWidth))
// Draw the inner bottom left corner
outterPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: shadowWidth + innerRadius, y: glowView.bounds.size.height - innerRadius - shadowWidth), radius: innerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, clockwise: false)

// Draw a line to the inner bottom right corner
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: glowView.bounds.size.width - innerRadius - shadowWidth, y: glowView.bounds.size.height - shadowWidth))
// Draw the inner bottom right corner
outterPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: glowView.bounds.size.width - innerRadius - shadowWidth, y: glowView.bounds.size.height - innerRadius - shadowWidth), radius: innerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)

// Draw a line to the inner top right corner
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: glowView.bounds.size.width - shadowWidth, y: shadowWidth + innerRadius))
// Draw the inner top right corner
outterPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: glowView.bounds.size.width - innerRadius - shadowWidth, y: shadowWidth + innerRadius), radius: innerRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: (3 * CGFloat.pi) / 2, clockwise: false)

// Draw a line to the inner top left corner
outterPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: shadowWidth + innerRadius, y: shadowWidth))
outterPath.close()
```