# How to do a shadow outside of the fill of a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, shadow

I have a cell with a translucent fill. Since the fill is translucent, I can see the shadow behind the fill. How can I hide the shadow under the cell's fill?

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 6
self.layer.masksToBounds = false
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6).cgColor  
self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
```

This is what I have:
[image: ScreenShot]
Desired result with transparent View:
[image: ScreenShot2]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or something? I'm not sure what 1) is happening and 2) what you'd like to happen.

Comment: I added screenshot to my answer

Comment: Sooo is that the current or the desired result?

Comment: this is current result, we can see shadow inside cell's frame. but I wish to see it only behind cell

Comment: Well I guess you'll have to decide between translucency and shadow.

Comment: it's so bad, but I hope there is solution of this problem

Comment: @SergeyHleb, please look into the shadowPath property on CALayer.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, I use it for another situation, but here it don't helps me

Comment: @SergeyHleb sure it does

Comment: @vikingosegundo, hmm. I don't know how. can you helps?

Comment: I'm with @LinusGeffarth on this one, however, here is an idea. You could use a rasterized shadow. I mean, make the effect in photoshop or similar, and use the image as a background of the view

Comment: Jeez @vikingosegundo, OP wanted help and if you know how to solve their issue, then just show them.

Comment: It's now very easy to do this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092828/294884  see the last section

Answer (score 0):

As per my Understanding you need this kind of View:

You can try this:

```
    let viewShadow = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    viewShadow.center = self.view.center
    viewShadow.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    viewShadow.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    viewShadow.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    viewShadow.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
    viewShadow.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    viewShadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    viewShadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 20.0, height:  20.0)
    viewShadow.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    self.view.addSubview(viewShadow)
```

**Output**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: View must be with alpha = 0.6, if in your variant I implements transparent, shadow become visible under the cell

Comment: I just suggested you the way i though it would help you. If it work for you or it helped you do upvote that or approve that @SergeyHleb, so that it praise us

Comment: it's not helps in my situation

Comment: So please can you explain what exactly you want.?

Comment: I would to see the shadow behind the fill, only, not under the translucent cell

Comment: sorry i did not understand, can you please expain that with a ScreenShot.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169441/discussion-between-abhirajsinh-thakore-and-sergey-hleb).

Comment: This is completely wrong, solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092828/294884

Answer (score -2):

This might help. All we need to do is alter the shadow path.

```
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6).cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
    let rect = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x, y: cell.frame.origin.y + cell.frame.size.height, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: 3)
    cell.layer.shadowPath = CGPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerWidth: 1, cornerHeight: 1, transform: nil)
```